# NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID Error with Chrome 66 using Apache JMeter as Proxy

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-4.0

Above mentioned privacy error is displaying while I tried to record some scenarios in Apache JMeter 4.0. I have installed **ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA** certificate in my local bin path of JMeter folder and imported in **Trusted Root Certification Authorities** folder in chrome.

And myself using Chrome : Version 66.0.3359.27 (Official Build) dev (32-bit) to recording purpose in JMeter. Also given 8080 as a **port number** in both proxy settings in chrome and JMeter - Test Script Recorder.

Still can't understand why I can't record several actions, as I did same thing in previous versions of Apache JMeter. So please let me know the solution for it.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following workarounds:

1. Just type [`badidea`](https://twilblog.github.io/chrome/security/2016/06/27/badidea.html) anywhere in the page and you will be able to proceed.
2. Launch Chrome with [`--ignore-certificate-errors`](https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/227989087-Chrome-for-Windows-only-HSTS-Certificate-Exception-Instructions) command-line argument
3. Switch to alternative way of recording a JMeter test using i.e. [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension), in this case you won't have to worry about configuring proxies and/or SSL certificates.

Comment: None of these are working for me...